# Minimal degrees of structures

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory

For this question, a *structure* means a first-order structure in a computable language with domain $\omega$; a *copy* of a structure $\mathcal{A}$ is a structure $\mathcal{B}\cong\mathcal{A}$.

---

Given a structure $\mathcal{A}$, we can try to understand the computability-theoretic complexity of $\mathcal{A}$ in various ways. One very natural approach is to analyze the **spectrum** of $\mathcal{A}$: $$Spec(\mathcal{A})=\{d: d\text{ computes a copy of $\mathcal{A}$}\}.$$ The spectrum is always(ish) closed upwards, but beyond that can be a very complicated object, so it is natural to consider the **degree** of $\mathcal{A}$: $$deg(\mathcal{A})=\min\{d: d\text{ computes a copy of $\mathcal{A}$}\}.$$ Unfortunately, not every structure has a degree: Linda Richter showed that, unless $\mathcal{A}$ is "locally complicated," then $Spec(\mathcal{A})$ contains a *minimal pair*: there are $d_0, d_1\in Spec(\mathcal{A})$ such that $d_0, d_1>_T0$ but $d_0\wedge d_1\equiv_T0$. If $\mathcal{A}$ does not have a computable copy, this means $deg(\mathcal{A})$ does not exist. For example, if $\mathcal{L}$ is a linear order with no computable copy, $\mathcal{L}$ has no degree.

This addresses the existence of *least* degrees of presentations; I'm wondering about *minimal* degrees of presentations. Say $d\in Spec(\mathcal{A})$ is *$\mathcal{A}$-minimal* if there is no $e\in Spec(\mathcal{A})$ with $e<_Td$.

Optimistically:

> Question 1: Does every structure $\mathcal{A}$ have an $\mathcal{A}$-minimal degree?

And in the opposite direction,

> Question 2: Is there a linear order $\mathcal{L}$ - with no computable copy - which has a $\mathcal{L}$-minimal degree?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Question 1: Does every structure $\mathcal{A}$ have an $\mathcal{A}$-minimal degree?

No. [Diamondstone, Greenberg, and Turetsky](http://diamondstone.me/natural_degree_spectra.pdf) show that the set of *array noncomputable* degrees is a degree spectrum.

And Downey, Jockusch and Stob showed that a degree is *array noncomputable* iff it computes a *pb-generic* set. Now if $G=A\oplus B$ is pb-generic, then so are $A$ and $B$, and they are strictly Turing below $A\oplus B$.

> Question 2: Is there a linear order $\mathcal{L}$ which has a $\mathcal{L}$-minimal degree?

Yes. [Russell Miller](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2695025?uid=3739632&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21106837731153) showed that there is a linear order whose degree spectrum includes every nonzero $\Delta^0_2$ degree, but not $\mathbf 0$.

And Sacks showed that there is a minimal Turing degree that is $\Delta^0_2$; so we are done.

## References

*David Diamondstone, Noam Greenberg, and Daniel Turetsky*, [**Natural large degree spectra**](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3123249), *Computability* **2** (2013), no. 1, 1--8.

*Russell Miller*, [**The $\Delta^0_2$-spectrum of a linear order**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2695025), *J. Symbolic Logic* **66** (2001), no. 2, 470--486.

Comment: For those, like me, who have not heard of pb-genericity before: http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0168007298000141/1-s2.0-S0168007298000141-main.pdf?_tid=a484c3ac-fb3e-11e4-983a-00000aab0f01&acdnat=1431720899_9ca74ec57c0c9414fe984b84b91ae59b

Comment: You don't need pb-genericity. It is not difficult to see that every ANC degree bounds a 1-generic degree (I think that it was already proved in the same DJS paper.)

Comment: @喻良 right, in fact pb-genericity implies 1-genericity.